# I want to get jquery to update checked box using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to get my ajax json script to update my HTML checked box with the value from my data base but cannot get it to work. Any help please.

The JS is below.

```js
  setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"databaseQuiry.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
     $('niamh').prop('checked', data.niamhswitch);
    }
   });
  }, 2000);
```

The HTML checked box I want updated is below

```html
 <div class="niamhSwitch">
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="niamh" id="switch" value="1">
 <div class="slider round"></div>
 </label></div>
```

I Know that the json is returning niamhswitch":"1" so I have the value 1 returning from my data base, but how do I get this to make the checked box become checked for value 1 and unchecked for value 0. I have tried doing it with the element selector for class and name but both do not work.

Comment: Use `$('#switch')` instead of `$('niamh')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector's wrong `$('niamh')` will look for an element whose tag name is 'niamh'.

You need either `$('[name=niamh]')` or `$('#switch')`.

Comment: great thanks. i new i could use the id but I have 3 switches with same id. I wanted to use either class or name selector. The $('[name=niamh]') worked thank you

Comment: This works but only when the return from json is 1. When it is 0 the switch is not updating to unchecked. Do you know why this is not working, or do i need to raise this as a separate question

Comment: Yes, because 0 is interpreted as a falsy value which, when passed to jQuery's `prop`(), is interpreted as false, i.e. DON'T check. 1 is truthy, i.e. DO check. Also, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID - it's invalid, and can cause problems with selectors.

Comment: That does not seem to work. If I have the following $('#boiler').prop('checked', data.boiler);  when boiler = 1 box is checked but when 0 box stays checked. However if I do the  following,                    if(data.boiler == '0'){
                     $('#boiler').prop('checked', false);}
                 else{
                  $('#boiler').prop('checked', true);}                        All is ok. Maybe its returning a string?not sure but the above works just long way around